# How to reuse identity password validation when changing passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm developing an asp.net core 2.1 project using Identity (UserManager, RoleManager), whose password settings are:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = false;
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;
        options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    });
```

I'm developing my own change password functionality but I would like to know if there is a way to take advantage of previous password settings (before mentioned Startup settings) to validate new password (eg: by injecting a service), avoiding to create a new password validator or maybe UserManager provides a way to validate?

Comment: which previous password settings?

Comment: before mentioned Startup settings

Comment: so you will like to know the default password settings of the application which is inheriting from Microsoft Identity Library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution by just using ChangePasswordAsync method of UserManager, it checks for passwords validation policies:

```
var result = await _userManager.ChangePasswordAsync(usuario, model.ContraseñaActual, model.ContraseñaNueva);
```

After that, checking boolean property result.Succeeded and result.Errors collection, I could validate message errors according validation policy.

Also thanks to Tao Zhou for the alternative help

Answer (score 4):

For `IPasswordValidator`, it is registered by

```
services.TryAddScoped<IPasswordValidator<TUser>, PasswordValidator<TUser>>();
```

For accessing `PasswordValidator<TUser>`, you could try

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser> _passwordValidator;
    public HomeController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager
        , IPasswordValidator<IdentityUser> passwordValidator)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _passwordValidator = passwordValidator;
    }
```

And then validate the password by

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    var result = _passwordValidator.ValidateAsync(_userManager, null, "123");

    return View();
}
```

For [PasswordValidator](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/c7276ce2f76312ddd7fccad6e399da96b9f6fae1/src/Core/PasswordValidator.cs#L39), it did not validate the user, so you could pass null.

Check the validate result in `var result`.